# How to make an event in a matrix of Button?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
int[,] matrixA =
    {
        {1,2,3,4,5 },
        {6,7,8,9,10 },
        {11,12,13,14,15 },
        {16,17,18,19,20 },
        {21,22,23,24,25 }

    };
Button[,] buttons = new Button[5, 5];
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                buttons[i, j] = new Button();
                buttons[i, j].Top = i * 30;
                buttons[i, j].Left = j * 100;
                buttons[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
                this.Controls.Add(buttons[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I want to click on each button, the corresponding index of matrixA will appear on that button, please help me, thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Control.Tag` property to provide data about the control, then utilize that in the click handler. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.8

When you're building your buttons:

```c#
// Other properties
buttons[i, j].Tag = matrixA[i, j];
// Add control
```

Then inside your click handler:

```c#
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Tag is type "object" so you have to cast to the desired type
    int matrixValue = (int)((sender as Button).Tag);
}
```

The other answer that mentions creating a custom class derived from `Button` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Tag' property.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            buttons[i, j] = new Button();
            buttons[i, j].Top = i * 30;
            buttons[i, j].Left = j * 100;

            buttons[i, j].Tag = 123; // put here the proper value from your array

            buttons[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(buttons[i, j]);
        }
    }
}
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int idx = (int)(sender as Button).Tag;
}
```